# Product URL issue in Observer Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product, event-observer, product-attribute, product-urls

I have create an Observer function which is call after product save but having some issues with product url.

**Getting product like:**

```
$product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
```

**Getting product url path:**

```
**$product->getUrlPath();  //Return empty path**

$product->getProductUrl(); //Show error for function
```

**//Finally I have used it**

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('default'); //set the default storeview
$url = Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getProductUrl($product->getId()); //get url for .html
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('admin'); //set the admin store again

But now the issue is url is shown as :
https://local.com/index.php/catalog/product/view/id/290/s/surestep-pro-diabetic-test-strips-50-strips-professional-care/

instead of 

http://local.com/surestep-pro-diabetic-test-strips-50-strips-professional-care.html
```

I want product .html url else url_path in observer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should fire the query directly on URL Rewrite table.

```
$productUrl = Mage::getResourceModel('core/url_rewrite')
        ->getRequestPathByIdPath('product/' . $productId, $storeId);
```

ou can try getting the product id as

```
$product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
$productId = $product->getId();
```

Hope it was helpful.
Thanks